# Acessar dicionario dentro de uma lista em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho a seguinte lista cuja elementos são dicionários:

```
[{'nome': 'ana', 'cpf': '1000', 'endereco': 'rua xxxx'}, {'nome': 'carlos', 'cpf': '7770', 'endereco': 'Rua aaaa'}]
```

Quero fazer a pesquisa pelo nome e cpf das pessoas

```
nome = input("Digite o nome que deseja buscar: ")
     for i in range(0, len(cl_cadastrados)):
        cl = cl_cadastrados[i]

        if (nome == cl['nome']):
            ...
            ...
```

Tem alguma forma mais simples de realizar este algorítimo? Existe alguma forma de acessar um dicionario dentro da lista diretamente sem utilizar uma variável auxiliar como estou fazendo. Ainda to me familiarizando com o Python estou mais acostumado em programar em C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soluções das outras respostas usam sempre um `for` para procurar os dados de forma sequencial, percorrendo todos os registros. Vou oferecer aqui duas soluções alternativas:

A primeira só pode ser usada **caso a lista já esteja ordenada por nome** - ela pesquisa usando árvore binária, ou seja, vai dividindo a lista em duas até achar a pessoa procurada. Bastante eficiente com muitas pessoas, e pode ser usada para achar a posição onde se deve inserir outra pessoa sem perder a ordenação da lista, bastando para isso passar um nome que não existe:

```
nomes = [d['nome'] for d in pessoas]

nome_procurado = 'maria'
n = bisect.bisect_left(nomes, nome_procurado) 
print(pessoas[n])
```

A segunda forma é a indexação - você usa o `for` uma única vez para criar um novo dicionário cuja chave é o nome, aí, basta usar esse dicionário para chegar direto nos dados quantas vezes quiser. Essa forma é melhor quando você vai procurar muitos nomes, pois a pesquisa no dicionário após indexado praticamente não tem custo:

```
indice_pessoas_por_nome = {d['nome']: d for d in pessoas}

nome_procurado = 'maria'
print(indice_pessoas_por_nome[nome_procurado])
```

Ambas as soluções podem ser utilizadas também para o CPF ou qualquer outro campo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar **compreensão de listas** se deseja simplificar:

```
pessoas = [{'nome': 'ana', 'cpf': '1000', 'endereco': 'rua xxxx'},
           {'nome': 'carlos', 'cpf': '8770', 'endereco': 'Rua aaaa'},
           {'nome': 'maria', 'cpf': '7770', 'endereco': 'Rua bbbb'}]

nome = 'maria'
cpf = '1000'

encontrados = [p for p in pessoas if p['nome'] == nome or p['cpf'] == cpf]
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode iterar sobre os elementos da lista da seguinte maneira:

```
for elm in cl_cadastrados:
    if nome == elm['nome']:
        ...
```

Dessa maneira você itera sobre os elementos de `cl_cadastrados` e acessa os elementos diretamente. É mais simples do ponto de vista de tamanho de código e de usar recursos do python, evitando iterar sobre os índices e acessando elementos de maneira mais otimizada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `next()`

```
pessoas = [{'nome': 'ana', 'cpf': '1000', 'endereco': 'rua xxxx'}, {'nome': 'carlos', 'cpf': '7770', 'endereco': 'Rua aaaa'}]
nome = 'carlos'

pessoa = next((p for p in pessoas if p['nome'] == nome), None)
print(pessoa)
```

Answer (score -2):

Simples!

```
    pessoas = [{'nome': 'ana', 'cpf': '1000', 'endereco': 'rua xxxx'}, 
{'nome': 'carlos', 'cpf': '7770', 'endereco': 'Rua aaaa'}]
```

Vamos supor que você queira acessar somente o 'nome':

```
print(pessoas[0]['nome'])
```